# Firefox - can I see what is partially encrypted or why I get that message?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer

In Firefox (and IE) you sometimes get a Connection Partially Encrypted.

[image]

[image]

Is there anyway to see what is not being sent via https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox(I'm using 3.6) you can use the **Tools** -> **Page Info** menu command to see information on the particular page.  Then select the **Media** tab to see the URLs for each of the elements on the page.  Anything that is not using `https://` is not encrypted.

In IE 8(maybe lower versions too) you can get a similar report by going to the **Safety** menu and selecting **Webpage Privacy Policy**.